# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException - when building Java Object using Protocol buffer

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, proto

I'm using Protobuff to build my Java object, why do I keep getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` Exception when calling `setHeader(0, h1)` in my code.

Here is my code:

```
        Person.Header h1 = Person.Header.newBuilder()
                .setKey("Key1")
                .setValue("value1")
                .build();

        Person person = Person.newBuilder()
                .setBody("TestBody")
                .setHeader(0, h1)
                .build();
```

Here is my protobuff message (call dataformat.proto):

```
syntax = "proto3";
package tutorial;

option java_package = "tutorial";

message Person {
    string body = 1;
    repeated Header header = 2;

    message Header {
        string key = 3;
        string value = 4;
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:453)
    at com.google.protobuf.ProtobufArrayList.set(ProtobufArrayList.java:96)
    at tutorial.Dataformat$Person.setHeader(Dataformat.java:572)
    at tutorial.Dataformat$Person.access$1200(Dataformat.java:42)
    at tutorial.Dataformat$Person$Builder.setHeader(Dataformat.java:815)
```

...

Comment: The error message says you are trying to access the first element of an empty List. you may want to check the lines in the stacktraces to check where it occurs, and add some validation

Comment: yes the stacktrace is pointing to this line in my code `setHeader(0, h1)` but I'm not sure what to do to fix it

Comment: post the relevant code in your question, do not add a link for us to click on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setHeader()` expects that the index already exists; it does not increase the list size. This is the same as `java.util.List`. You can use `addHeader()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For repeated List data type, simply use `add***` instead of `set***`
So in your example, you can use `addHeader(...)` instead of `setHeader(...)`